# unwanted changes after clicking on a custom button created with ribbon editor

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

in MS Dynamics CRM 2016,I've created a new button on opportunity form with Visual Ribbon editor.

my button calls a dialog in order to get some extra information about account. everything's working fine , the problem is that after finishing the dialog as it is connected to my button , it refreshes the form and a new empty opportunity will be create.

when I check all opportunities I see my created opportunity, but why it creates a new opportunity after button is clicked ?

Comment: Can you please show your code that launches your dialog?

Comment: without any sourcecode, it's impossible to write any useful answer